# Similar xlims and ylims succinctly in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the following code to generate biplot as given below.

```
library(ggfortify)
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]
autoplot(prcomp(df)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

[image: gg]

I wonder how to get similar xlims and ylims succinctly so that all four quadrants are exactly of same size.

**Edited**

```
library(ggfortify)
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]

autoplot(prcomp(df), data = iris, colour = 'Species',
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I realised why you have different values for your PCA - you need to scale the values first!  you can just do this in the prcomp call `prcomp(iris[1:4], scale. = TRUE)` (or use `FactoMineR::PCA`

Comment: You may have taken the example from the ggfortify vignette - but their example was erroneous. The vignette has been updated on github https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/master/vignettes/plot_pca.Rmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note my comment about scaling your data before performing PCA . Now, [biplots can also be actually scaled in multiple ways](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141085/positioning-the-arrows-on-a-pca-biplot).

**To your question**. I think the easiest approach would be to pull the maximum x/y coordinates for your individuals from the PCA object - and use them as limits. This is **for using actual PCA values!**. The scaled version depends on how you scale it. See below for one method.

Option 1 **with the actual PCA values**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

df <- iris[1:4]

res.pca <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

cmax <- res.pca$x[which.max(res.pca$x)] #get variable coordinates

autoplot(res.pca, data = iris, colour = 'Species',
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3, 
         scale = FALSE) + # scale = FALSE!
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-cmax,cmax), ylim = c(-cmax,cmax)) 

# also using coord_equal, so that it looks equal
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Option 2 - One different way of scaling** [This thread shows how (one way of) scaling is done under the hood.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/66933/221162)

From this, you can obtain the maximum limits for the scaled biplot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

df <- iris[1:4]

res.pca <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)

choices <- 1L:2L
scale <- 1
pc.biplot <- FALSE
scores <- res.pca$x
lam <- res.pca$sdev[choices]
n <- NROW(scores)
lam <- lam * sqrt(n)
lam <- lam^scale
bi_vec <- t(t(res.pca$rotation[, choices]) * lam)
bi_ind <- t(t(scores[, choices]) / lam)

cmax <- bi_ind[which.max(bi_ind)]

autoplot(res.pca, data = iris, colour = 'Species',
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-cmax,cmax), ylim = c(-cmax,cmax))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>